# resolving openshift disk quota usage

Tags: wordpress, openshift, diskspace

I'm using a WordPress small gear cartridge on OpenShift.

Warnings about the app's disk usage being >95% of its quota.

> Warning: Gear...is using 99.5% of disk quota

This results in the gear going offline.  Download the app, the .tar file is only about 55MB.  I've used the below tidy command, got the "Success" response without resolving the issue.

> rhc app-tidy [appname]

Any advice how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7):

SSH into your gear and run

```
du -hc
```

And see what is taking up so much space
you can also try

```
du | sort -n
```

to get everything sorted from smallest to largest

Comment: This was helpful to view the disk usage.  After SFTPing into the gear and deleting some backup files accounting for about 1/4 of the size quota, the gear still seems to have the same usage, per the quota -s command.  I also tried using the tidy-app command, which returns "Failed to execute: 'control start'".  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Don't know if OpenShift is having issues but running the tidy command now responds:"TidyCompOp failed on 1 gear. Please try again and contact support if the issue persists."

Comment: Thanks, these commands helped me to find out that there were way to many log files laying around.